# There is no apt-get install ruby1.9.2 yet on Linux?

Tags: ruby, rvm, apt-get

The page http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ only says 1.9.1 for Linux.

Right now I am using RVM to do an

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

and it needs compilation.  There is no apt-get install way to install it?

Is there a way to list all Ruby version apt-get can install?

Comment: Personally, unless I have to make a particular version of Ruby available to all users on a machine, either in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin, I go with rvm. It offers a lot of nice functionality for individual developers, including the ability to have multiple gem sets and very fast installation of new versions of Ruby. And, `rvm list known` will show the versions available to rvm.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ruby or even programming. Figuring out how to use your operating system's package manager is a question for SuperUser.Com. (Just as an experiment: replace all occurences of *Ruby* in the question with *Tetris* and it's still the same question.)

Comment: @Jorg: Do you think both questions belong on SU, or just the second question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To list available versions you can use the following command:

```
 apt-cache search --names-only '^ruby1.*'
```

If you use Debian, 1.8, 1.9, 1.9.1 are availble on testing. 1.9.2 is only available on unstable.

Answer (score 4):

in debian squeeze and sid the 1.9.1 package is in fact based on the 1.9.2 branch according to this search:
http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ruby1.9.1&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

and the changelog says that too:
http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/r/ruby1.9.1/ruby1.9.1_1.9.2~svn28788-1/changelog

Answer (score 1):

It's only been 3 weeks, give it some time :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for ruby1.9.1

```
ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

rvm now supports binary rubies, so there is no need to compile:

```
rvm get head # this change will be available in rvm 1.16
rvm list remote
rvm mount 1.9.3
```

only ruby 1.9.3 is good for installing in relative paths so do not expect earlier versions to be available (for other path then /usr/local/rvm).

if `rvm list remote` was empty then let me know what is your system `rvm info`, you can find me on irc **mpapis** at #rvm at freenode servers or open a ticket here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/new